# Enumerate DriveItem resources of a specific Drive given SharePoint URL and using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I have a SharePoint URL of the form https://organizationname.sharepoint.com/sites/....

I want to use the Graph API to get a list of all resources in this drive. Reading the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onedrive?view=graph-rest-1.0) it appears that I require the **drive-id** of this drive in order to perform this request.

```
/drives/{drive-id}/root/children
```

Also, according to the answer to a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351018/to-get-drive-id-from-sharepoint-url/63540434#63540434) it appears there are no APIs to convert SharePoint URL to OneDrive driveId. Is there a possible workaround? Is there any way to programmatically get a list of resources from a SharePoint URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SharePoint URL is `https://organizationname.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSiteName`, then you can issue a request like this via the Graph API (scope `Sites.Read.All` might be required):

```
client.api("/sites/organizationname.sharepoint.com:/sites/yourSiteName:/drives").get();
```

That request will return something like this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#drives",
    "value": [
        {
            "createdDateTime": "2021-07-24T23:35:00Z",
            "description": "",
            "id": "b!A1234567-ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2021-08-12T16:39:23Z",
            "name": "Dokumente",
            "webUrl": "https://organizationname.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSIteName/folderName",
            "driveType": "documentLibrary",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "displayName": "abc"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "bla@organizationame.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "12345678-4321-4321-4321-012345678901",
                    "displayName": "zz"
                }
            },
            "owner": {
                "group": {
                    "email": "x@y.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "09876543-1234-1234-1234-012345678901",
                    "displayName": "Owner of something"
                }
            },
            "quota": {
                "deleted": 345678,
                "remaining": 27487788453406,
                "state": "normal",
                "total": 27487790694400,
                "used": 96120
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The `id` under `description` is the `drive-id`. With that you can get `/root/children` like so:

```
client.api("/sites/yourorganizationname.sharepoint.com/drives/b!A1234567-ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA9876543210/root/children").get();
```

While there is no single API or algorithm that allows you to programmatically get a list of resources from a SharePoint URL, you can achieve the same with two Graph API requests.